# Wine in Ubuntu cannot create temporary directory error?

Tags: python, wine, python3

I am trying to run an .exe file made from pyinstaller to run on Ubuntu 16.04 with Wine, but it always gives me the following error:

```
[42] INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!
002b:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x22fac0 (nil)): stub
```

I built the .exe on my Windows 8 machine with Python 3.8.4 and pyinstaller 3.6.

Comment: I am just commenting the solution that worked for me, although it is not advisable at all. Wine was not getting appropriate permissions to make a temp file in temp folder, I tried everything and nothing worked, then I got to this solution. I ran the exe with wine with root access `sudo`, which the winehq website also discourages strongly. Until I discover a better solution, I am going to go with this.

Comment: Did you find an alternative than running with `sudo`?